# Does it androidx have support for camerax?

Tags: android, android-camera, androidx, android-camerax

I am wondering if camerax is supported on both Java and kotlin. I did not found any Java sample about camerax and the only samples that I found are in kotlin language.

Could you Point me any link to a camerax sample that takes a picture in Java language or just tell me if camerax is supported also on androidx?

Any feedback is highly apreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look [at this app](https://github.com/thunderedge/CameraX) which is unofficial but implemented using camerax package `androidx.camera.core.CameraX;`

He seems to have followed [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/) codelab and translated it into Java from Kotlin.

Comment: private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};**};** //array w/ permissions from manifest . It works perfect after I removed the last acolade. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke kotlin from java and vice verse.

Comment: I know but i do not want to mix it